# Gitlab job not pulling Docker image

Tags: docker, gitlab, dockerfile, gitlab-ci

Running a Gitlab project that uses a Docker image I created.

Problem: Gitlab job execution log shows that image is not being pulled.
[image]
Here is the .gitlab-ci.yml file, with the company stuff removed:

```
default:
  image:
    name: guythedocker/jmeter-mssql-windows:latest
    entrypoint: [""]

api test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - get-variable
    - $env:path -split ";"
    - echo $WORKDIR
    - Get-ChildItem  -Path / -File
    - entrypoint.ps1 --version
    - |
      /entrypoint.ps1 -n -t ./JMeter/xxx.jmx -l ./xxx.log -e -o ./testresults/xxx-Jthreads=$xx-Jrampup=$xxx -JtestCases=$xxx -Jhost=xxx.com -f 

  retry: 2

  only:
    - schedules
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - testresults
  tags:
   - win2019
```

Here is the Dockerfile, which is essentially copied from QAInsights' Dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile for Apache JMeter for Windows
# Indicates that the windowsservercore along with OpenJDK will be used as the base image.
# Based on work by NaveenKumar Namachivayam 
FROM openjdk:8-windowsservercore

ARG JMETER_VERSION="5.4.3"
ENV JMETER_HOME /apache-jmeter-$JMETER_VERSION/apache-jmeter-$JMETER_VERSION/

# Metadata indicating an image maintainer.
LABEL maintainer="Guy L."

# Downloads JMeter from one of the mirrors, if you prefer to change, you can change the URL
RUN Invoke-WebRequest -URI https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-$env:JMETER_VERSION.zip \
-UseBasicParsing -Outfile /apache-jmeter-$env:JMETER_VERSION.zip

# Extract the downloaded zip file
RUN Expand-Archive /apache-jmeter-$env:JMETER_VERSION.zip -DestinationPath /apache-jmeter-$env:JMETER_VERSION

# For JDBC
RUN Invoke-WebRequest -URI https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/microsoft/sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/9.4.1.jre8/mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar -Outfile mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar 
RUN Invoke-WebRequest -URI https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/microsoft/sqlserver/mssql-jdbc_auth/9.4.1.x86/mssql-jdbc_auth-9.4.1.x86.dll -Outfile mssql-jdbc_auth-9.4.1.x86.dll
    
COPY ./mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar ${JMETER_HOME}/lib/
COPY ./mssql-jdbc_auth-9.4.1.x86.dll ${JMETER_HOME}/lib/

# Copies the entrypoint.ps1
COPY /entrypoint.ps1 /entrypoint.ps1
COPY /jmeter-plugins-install.ps1 /jmeter-plugins-install.ps1

RUN ["powershell.exe","/jmeter-plugins-install.ps1"]
# Sets the Working directory
WORKDIR ${JMETER_HOME}/bin

# Sets a command or process that will run each time a container is run from the new image. For detailed instruction, go to entrypoint.ps1 file.
ENTRYPOINT ["powershell.exe", "/entrypoint.ps1"]
```

The image was [successfully published](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/guythedocker/jmeter-mssql-windows).

So why is my Gitlab project not pulling this image?

It is a Windows runner (since I'm using the `-tag`, and as I can see in the Job history).

Comment: It's because your runner is configured to use `shell` executor. Check [docker](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html) executor instead.

Comment: Appreciate the quick response.  So it sounds like I need the Gitlab admin to do this, right?

Comment: you need to have enough rights to modify runner config and register it

Comment: @NicolasPepinster - I'll be glad to mark this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your runner is configured to use `shell` executor (as you can see line 3 of your printscreen) but to run Docker image, you have to use `docker` or `docker-windows` [executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html) (depending of if container you want to run is Linux or Windows based).